# Positively oriented circle

Tags: complex-numbers

I wish to have a positively circle centered around $z_0 = -1 +2i$ with radius $3$. Clearly, the circle is $|z - z_0| = \rho = 3$. And written out we have $ \sqrt{(x + 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2} = 3$. I am having trouble making this circle positively oriented.

I know I want to parametrize this, but i'm having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what kind of parameterization you want, you could just take the usual parameterization of the circle at the origin and then translate it.

So, for example, since $3e^{2\pi i t}$ traces out the circle of radius 3 at the origin with $t\in [0,1)$, you can parameterize the given circle by $3e^{2\pi i t} -1 +2i$.  And then you can use Euler's formula if you want an expression in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah, okay. I have one question: Why do we need the $2\pi$ multiply $it$ there? I forget what happens when we have a coefficient there.

Comment: You don't necessarily need the factor of $2\pi$ in your expression.  You could use Greg's parameterization and let $t$ range from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Comment: The basic fact is that $e^{it}$ traces out a circle of radius 1 as long as your input $t$ is real.  So we can scale and translate this circle to get what we want.

Comment: Okay. To get $f(t) = -1 +2i + 3e^{it} = -1 + 2i + 3\cos(t)+3i\sin(t)$ into the form $z(t) = x(t) + iy(t)$, we simply group to get: $z(t) = f(t) = \underbrace{-1 + 3(\cos(t) + \sin(t))}_{x(t)} + i\underbrace{2}_{y(t)}$.

Comment: Exactly.  There's a small mistake, though, in that your $y(t)$ term should get be $3\sin(t)+2$.  You lost an $i$ somewhere.

Comment: Whoops. We should then have $-1 + 3\cos(t) + i(2 + 3\sin(t))$ then.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f:[0,2 \pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(t)=-1+2i+3e^{it}$